pdfx workaround breaks itemize
I compiled this MWE
\RequirePackage[2024-05-01]{latexrelease}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfx}

\begin{document}

This is NOT an item.

\begin{itemize}
\item This is an item.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}

with
lualatex -interaction=nonstopmode ./foo.tex
echo $? # in Bash this command prints exit code of lualatex, it is 1

I had to add the first line to solve a pdfx issue as suggested here.
Unfortunately, lualatex complains:
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

If I comment out itemize environment, everything will work.
The same error message also appears if you comment out \item.

Try a version/date before 2023-06-01 instead of 2024-05-01.

note that getting the item error on rollback happens even without pdfx and is a bug:  https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/1386

Note, that you don't need the workaround any longer. The new version of pdfx does not load package xmpincl inside a group. So you can remove \RequirePackage[2024-05-01]{latexrelease}. Also the new version of latexrelease can correctly rollback without error. So an update would fix both issues.

I would not roll back latex, especially if you are interested in tagging.
Packages should never have been loaded in a group but you can silence the check just while loading pdfx by hiding the group level
%\RequirePackage[2024-05-01]{latexrelease}

\documentclass{article}

\let\foo\currentgrouplevel
\chardef\currentgrouplevel0
\usepackage{pdfx}
\let\currentgrouplevel\foo

\begin{document}

This is NOT an item.

\begin{itemize}
\item This is an item.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}

The package in principle should not work correctly when loaded this way but if it worked well enough before the check was added, this should make it do the same.
